# Remap [zmiros] synonym

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

Can the [zmiros](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zmiros) synonym be remapped from [song-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-poetry) to [shabbat-songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs), which seems to be a more appropriate usage?

Comment: To evaluate this, it would be helpful if we had some data about the current usage.  How many of the currently-tagged questions *aren't* about Shabbat songs?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Pretty much all, as it's currently a synonym of [song-poetry], which is, IMO, unintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

As *zmiros* is a generic term that could apply to Shabbat songs, Chanuka songs, or any other songs ([Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073I1ALU) is an example of the term modified by both *Shabbos* and *Yom Tov*.), I think that mapping a tag by that name to the general [songs-poetry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/songs-poetry) tag is more correct than mapping it to the specific [shabbat-songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs) tag.

However, I think it would be appropriate to create a synonym for the latter that incorporates the word *zmiros*, or some transliterative variation thereof, so that it will come up on the command completion, since people *will* sometimes, although not always, type in this word while thinking "Shabbat songs." So, I propose [zmiros-shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zmiros-shabbos) and [zemirot-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zemirot-shabbat) as a synonyms for [shabbat-songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs).